# get the most recent two dates for a customer MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve the last two dates for customers with entries in at least two different dates, implying there are some customer who had purchased only in one date, the table is as follow

```
client_id  date
1          2016-07-02
1          2016-07-02
1          2016-06-01
2          2015-06-01
```

as a response, I would get

```
client_id      previous_date     last_date
1              2016-06-01        2016-07-02
```

important:

a client can have multiple entries for the same date

a client can have entries only for one date, such customer should be discarded

Comment: You appear to have no PRIMARY KEY, which makes this kind of problem difficult, and a broader suite of similar problems effectively impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `group by` the client_id column, with a `having` of `count(*) > 1` to find results with more than one result. Then do a check of the `min` and `max` date, to ensure they aren't the same. Then just `select` the date, and `order` the results by date in `desc` order, with a `limit` of 2.

```
select 
    date
from 
    my_table
group by 
    client_id 
having 
    min(date) <> max(date)
    and count(*) > 1
order by
    date desc
limit 2
```